# Проблема из событиями у UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, usercontrol

Есть Usercontrol которий находится у папке Vkstatistics/Templates. Vkstatistics - им'я проекта. Проблема состоится в том что при визове события (нажатия кнопки, наведения фокуса курсора мыши) выбивает ошибка: 
'LoginControl" не содержит определения для "Send_Data_Button" и не удалось найти метод расширения "Send_Data_Button", принимающий тип "LoginControl" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)

LoginContrl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="VkStatistic.Templates.LoginControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VkStatistic.Templates"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Height="400" Width="600">
    <Grid Background="#FF878282">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="0 70 0 0"
                  FontSize="18"
                  Foreground="Black">
                For continue you must pass authorization
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock FontSize="15"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="0 100 0 0"
                       Foreground="Gray">
                    Login in your exist account VK
        </TextBlock>

        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="150" Width="200"
                    Margin="0 50 0 0">
            <TextBlock Margin="25 0 0 0">Input email or phone</TextBlock>

            <TextBox 
                 x:Name="LoginBox"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 Height="25" Width="150"
                Margin="0 0 0 0"
                Focusable="True"
                GotFocus="GotFocusLogin"
                LostFocus="LostFocusLogin"
                />
            <TextBlock Margin="25 15 0 0">Input password</TextBlock>
            <PasswordBox 
                 x:Name="PaswrdBox"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 Height="25" Width="150"
                 />


            <Button x:Name="LoginButton"
                    Height="25" Width="70"
                    Margin="80 15 0 0"
                    Content="Log in"
                    Click="Send_Data_Button"/>

        </StackPanel>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

LoginControl.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

using VkStatistic.Templates;

namespace VkStatistic.Templates
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для LoginControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class LoginControlVM: UserControl
    {
        public LoginControlVM()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            RegisterStyle();
        }

        void RegisterStyle()
        {
            LoginBox.Text = "email or phone";
            LoginBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        }


        private void GotFocusLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;

            if (txt.Text == "email or phone")
            {
                txt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                txt.Text = "";
            }
        }

        void LostFocusLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;

            if (txt.Text == "")
            {
                txt.Text = "email or phone";
                txt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
            }
        }


        void Send_Data_Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string login = LoginBox.Text;
            string password = PaswrdBox.Password.ToString();
            Debug.WriteLine(password);
        }


    }
}
```

Использую его у главном окне:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:LoginControlV}">
            <vms:LoginControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
           .........................................
</Window.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentContentVM}"/>
```

Использую паттерн MVVM, в чем может быть проблема???

Comment: Что-то вы делаете капитально не то. А как вы создавали `LoginContrl.xaml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас

```
public partial class LoginControlVM: UserControl
{
    public LoginControlVM()
    {
```

A должно быть

```
public partial class LoginControl: UserControl
{
    public LoginControl()
    {
```

Comment: пробовал так, возникает ошибка: Разделяемые объявления "LoginControl" не должны указывать различные базовые классы.

Comment: Видимо есть еще код вида "public partial class LoginControl". Нужно его найти и удалить

Comment: нет больше, у меня есть еще один UserControl MainControl.xaml, там та же проблема

Comment: Сделайте поиск строки "partial class LoginControl" по проекту через Ctrl+Shift+F. Сколько найдет совпадений?

Comment: нашло только инициализацию класа LoginControlVM. Думаю что проблема в подключение, но текст з TextBox могу визвать в коде и работает, а вот события Click, GotFocus, LostFocus - нет

Comment: Исправьте, как я написал. И покажите, где возникает ошибка.

Comment: Вот здесь: public partial class LoginControl: UserControl

Comment: Можете выложить куда-нибудь проект?

Comment: Так же советую прочитать: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/2.2.php

Comment: Могу на GitHub, может имеете свой аккаунт телеграм, скину приватно

Comment: Проще через google/yandex диск и выложить прямую ссылку.

Comment: Немного помучился, отредактировал код, поудалял лишнее елементи. Что-то протупил з тем, что название окна .xaml должно совпадать з названием класа для роботи з ним